# Don't keep Activity in cache with TabLayout

Tags: java, android, caching, android-activity, tabwidget

Here is my application structure : I have a main Activity with 4 tabs (Account, Dashboard, Medias, Applications). Each tab is linked to an Activity. The Applications tab contains many Activities and, in order to keep the tabs visible, I do if/else in my ApplicationsActivity to know wich layout I have to display (probably not the best way to do this, but I didn't find anything better).

My problem : When I go in my Applications tab, I see a list of all applications, then I click on one application, I get a new screen with options for this application, I click on one option, I get a new screen, etc.
Then I click on the Medias tab, I get a list of all the Medias.
Then I click on the Applications tab again, and I'm still on the screen with options of a specific application.
What I want is to come back to the list of all applications.

How can I do that ? How can I do to tell the tab that it has to reload the activity and not take it in what it seems to be a cache ?

Here is my Main Activity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
private int currentTab = 1;
private Application application = null;
private String optionType = null;
private String checkID = null;
private String alertID = null;
private int periodID = -1;
private Statistic stat = null;
private Media media = null;
TabHost tabHost;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PreferencesManager.load(this);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Log.i("IV", bundle.toString());

        String applicationID = null;
        applicationID = bundle.getString("applicationID");
        if (applicationID != null) {
            try {
                this.application = Utils.getApplication(applicationID);
            } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ApiCallErrorException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InternalErrorException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            this.application = (Application) bundle
                    .getSerializable("application");
        }

        this.currentTab = bundle.getInt("currentTab", 1);
        this.optionType = bundle.getString("optionType");
        this.checkID = bundle.getString("checkID");
        this.alertID = bundle.getString("alertID");
        this.periodID = bundle.getInt("periodID", -1);
        this.stat = (Statistic) bundle.getSerializable("stat");
        this.media = (Media) bundle.getSerializable("media");
    }

    Log.i("IV", "current tab : " + currentTab);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            //Log.i("IV", "Tab id : " +tabId);
            setTabColor(); 
        }
    });

    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AccountActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("account")
            .setIndicator(getString(R.string.account),
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_account))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("dashboard")
            .setIndicator(getString(R.string.dashboard),
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_dashboard))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MediasActivity.class).putExtra(
            "media", media);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("medias")
            .setIndicator(getString(R.string.medias),
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_media))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ApplicationsActivity.class)
            .putExtra("application", application)
            .putExtra("optionType", optionType)
            .putExtra("checkID", checkID).putExtra("alertID", alertID)
            .putExtra("periodID", periodID).putExtra("stat", stat);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("applications")
            .setIndicator(getString(R.string.applications),
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_application))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    setTabColor();

    if (!PreferencesManager.getBoolean("isLogged")) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).setEnabled(false);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(102, 102, 102));
        }
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    } else {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    }
}

public void setTabColor() {
    for(int i=0;i<this.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        this.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); //unselected
    }
    this.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(this.tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ABABAB")); // selected
}
}
```

In my ApplicationsActivity I just do if/else on values in the bundle to know what layout to use with setContentView();

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I don;t know If are understand your problem, but maybe try in android manifest file change your activity settings and add:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: I already tried this but I want the back button to work. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to user an ActivityGroup inside your TabActivity? With an ActivityGroup you could easily get rid of the whole if-else-thing.

This would actually solve your problem:
[Going back to previous TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841950/going-back-to-previous-tabactivity/5924360#5924360)