# Android Tab Activity go back when click on selected tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

I am working on app on which i am working on tabactivity,at first screen i have some buttons,when i click on button the home tab activity launch,and the home tab activity is selected,now i want when the home tab activity is selected when i click on selected home tab activity it goes back,can it is possible?

This is the tab activity when it is launched,the home tab is selected,and i want it to when i click again the selected home tab it goes back to previous activity,any solution will be much appreciated Thanks.
[image]

This is my first activity code when i click on button:

```
new_car.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent newCar_intent = new Intent(Car_shop_home.this, Used_vehicle_tabbarnew.class);
        newCar_intent.putExtra("csHeader_logo", getIntent().getExtras().getString("csHeader_logo"));
        newCar_intent.putExtra("csMakeName", getIntent().getExtras().getString("csMakeName"));
        newCar_intent.putExtra("csMakeID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("csMakeID"));
        newCar_intent.putExtra("bCarShop", true);
        newCar_intent.putExtra("vehicle_type", "1");
        newCar_intent.putExtra("DealerEmergencyNumbers", getIntent().getExtras().getString("DealerEmergencyNumbers"));

        startActivity(newCar_intent); 


        //startActivity(k);
    }
   });
```

and this is my tabbar class:

```
public class Used_vehicle_tabbarnew extends TabActivity{
String csMakeName;
String csMakeID;
String csDealerID;
Bundle CarData;
String csAdvert;
String csImageUrl;
String csHeader_logo;
ProgressDialog myPd_ring;

JSONArray jsonNumberArray;
List<String> emergencyNumberList=new ArrayList<String>();
String csEmergencyNumber = "";
String csSavedDealerID;
String DealerEmergencyNumbers = "";
private ArrayAdapter<String> myEmergencyAdapter;

boolean emergency = false;

TextView title;
TextView title1;
TextView title2;
TextView title3;

int tabClick = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.e("CMH", "In Tabbar");

    final TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();
    createUsedVehicleTab(mTabHost);
    createFinanceTab(mTabHost);
//  createEmergencyTab(mTabHost);
    createFavouritesTab(mTabHost);
//  createMoreTab(mTabHost);
    createProfileTab(mTabHost);

    DealerEmergencyNumbers =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("DealerEmergencyNumbers");


     csHeader_logo=getIntent().getExtras().getString("csHeader_logo");
     getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {


        @Override
           public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
           {

               if (getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("tab_emergency"))
               { 
                   UpdateList();
                   if(csSavedDealerID == null)
                       showMessage("To benefit from the full features of this app please fill in your profile.");
                   else
                       showCutomMessage("Would you like to call for emergency assistance");  

                   emergency = true;
                   mTabHost.setCurrentTab(tabClick);


               }
               else if (emergency == true)
               {
                   emergency = false;
               }
               else if (getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("tab_home"))
               { 
                   finish();
               }
               tabClick = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();

               if(tabClick == 0) {
                    //   title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                       title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a30000"));
                   }else{
                       title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                   }
                   if(tabClick == 1) {
                       title1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a30000"));
                   }else{
                       title1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                   }
                   if(tabClick == 2) {
                       title2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a30000"));
                   }else{
                       title2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                   }
                   if(tabClick == 3) {
                       title3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a30000"));
                   }else{
                       title3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                   }


             }
           });


}

public void createUsedVehicleTab(TabHost mTabHost)
{
    // Create Intent for My Info

      csMakeID=getIntent().getExtras().getString("csMakeID");
      csHeader_logo=getIntent().getExtras().getString("csHeader_logo");
      String csMakeName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("csMakeName");

    Intent intent_settings = new  Intent(Used_vehicle_tabbarnew.this,Used_vehicle_group_actvitynew.class);
    //intent_settings.putExtras(CarData);

    intent_settings.putExtra("csMakeID",csMakeID);
    intent_settings.putExtra("csMakeName",csMakeName);
    intent_settings.putExtra("csHeader_logo", csHeader_logo);
    intent_settings.putExtra("bCarShop",  getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("bCarShop", false));
    intent_settings.putExtra("vehicle_type",  getIntent().getExtras().getString("vehicle_type"));

     TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_used_home");       

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, getTabWidget(), false);

        title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        title.setText("Home");
        title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a30000"));
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_home);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent_settings);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);


        int height = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height;

        //Log.e("CMH", "tab Hight " + height);
}


public void createFinanceTab(TabHost mTabHost)
{
    // Create Intent for My Info

    Intent intent_settings = new Intent(Used_vehicle_tabbarnew.this,
            Finance.class);

    intent_settings.putExtra("csHeader_logo", csHeader_logo);
    intent_settings.putExtra("bCarShop",  getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("bCarShop", false));
    // mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_my_info").setIndicator(language.txt_myinfo[language.language], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_my_info)).setContent(intent_my_info));

     TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_finance");     

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, getTabWidget(), false);

         title1 = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        title1.setText("Finance");
        title1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_finance);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent_settings);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
}


public void createFavouritesTab(TabHost mTabHost)
{
    // Create Intent for My Info

    Intent intent_settings = new Intent(Used_vehicle_tabbarnew.this,
            Favourities.class);

    intent_settings.putExtra("bCarShop", true);
    intent_settings.putExtra("csHeader_logo", csHeader_logo);
    intent_settings.putExtra("Previous_Activity", "More_group_activity");
    // mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_my_info").setIndicator(language.txt_myinfo[language.language], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_my_info)).setContent(intent_my_info));

     TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_favourites");      

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, getTabWidget(), false);

         title2 = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        title2.setText("My favourites");
        title2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_favourites);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent_settings);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);


}



public void createProfileTab(TabHost mTabHost)
{
    // Create Intent for My Info

    Intent intent_settings = new Intent(Used_vehicle_tabbarnew.this,
            MyProfile.class);

    intent_settings.putExtra("bCarShop", true);
    intent_settings.putExtra("csHeader_logo", csHeader_logo);
    intent_settings.putExtra("Previous_Activity", "More_group_activity");
    // mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_my_info").setIndicator(language.txt_myinfo[language.language], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_my_info)).setContent(intent_my_info));

     TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_profile");     

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, getTabWidget(), false);

         title3 = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        title3.setText("My profile");
        title3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_profile);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent_settings);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);



}

 public void showCutomMessage(String message)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton(
                "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {

                        dialog.cancel();

                        if(csEmergencyNumber.length() <= 0 && emergencyNumberList.size() <= 0)
                        {
                            showMessage("No Emergency Number found.");
                         }
                         else if (csEmergencyNumber.length() > 0)
                         {
                             String url = "tel:" + csEmergencyNumber;
                             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                             startActivity(intent);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if (emergencyNumberList.size() == 1)
                             {
                                 String url = "tel:" + emergencyNumberList.get(0);
                                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                                 startActivity(intent);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 showEmergencyNumberDialog();
                             }
                         }

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(
                        "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                            {

                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });


        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setMessage(message);


        alert.show();

    }

 public void UpdateList()
 {
     try
        {
            emergencyNumberList.clear();
            jsonNumberArray = new JSONArray(DealerEmergencyNumbers.toString());

            SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Used_vehicle_tabbarnew.this);
            csSavedDealerID = app_preferences.getString("DealerID", null);

            for(int nJasonIndex = 0; nJasonIndex < jsonNumberArray.length(); nJasonIndex++)
            {
                JSONObject emergencyObj =jsonNumberArray.getJSONObject(nJasonIndex);
                String csNumber = emergencyObj.getString("EmergencyNumber");
                String csNumber2 = emergencyObj.getString("office_hours_num"); 

                String csMakeDealerID = emergencyObj.getString("DealerID");
                if(csSavedDealerID != null && csSavedDealerID.equalsIgnoreCase(csMakeDealerID))
                {
                    csEmergencyNumber = csNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!csNumber.equals(""))
                        emergencyNumberList.add("After Hours: " + csNumber);

                    if(!csNumber2.equals(""))
                        emergencyNumberList.add("Office Hours: " + csNumber2);
                }

            }

            if(emergencyNumberList.size() > 1)
            {
                myEmergencyAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,emergencyNumberList); 
                myEmergencyAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }

 public void showMessage(String message)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton(
                "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });


        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setMessage(message);


        alert.show();

    }

 void showEmergencyNumberDialog()
 {
     ArrayAdapter adapter = new  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, emergencyNumberList);

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setTitle("");
     builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
         {
             if (item >= 0)
             {
                 String emergencyNumber = emergencyNumberList.get(item);
                 String[] parts = emergencyNumber.split(": ");
                 String number = parts[1]; // 034556

                 String url = "tel:" + number;
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(intent);
             }

         }
     });

     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.show();
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't quite follow your question.  It would be great if your can explain again, maybe a point form.  My understanding is, you want to have different behaviour depends if the "Home" button is selected or first selected.

Here is my answer for overriding the TabHost's default handling routine when selecting a tab:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475299/3731039

I think my solution is not the direct one for you.  If you explain further, I might modify my answer for you.

Initialize the tab:

```
TabWidget w = tabHost.getTabWidget();
View view = w.getChildAt(w.getChildCount() - 1);
// here is the magic!
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handleHomeSelected();
    }
});
```

Your custom action:

```
protected void handleHomeSelected(){
    // do your logic
}
```